# How to represent in uml a class which takes another class and sets its self as a member on it

Tags: uml

[image]

In the picture above class of the type implementation will at some point receive a class of type C1. Classes that implement Contact will at some point hold references to C1.

So should the diagram be more like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your first diagram is almost correct:

- Despite popular beliefs, the shared aggregation has [no particular semantic defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664903/3723423), according to UML specifications (for more than 20 years!). It has no different meaning than a simple association. It does not imply that a reference is necessarily held.
- To formally express in UML that object `C1` holds a reference to the `Implementation`, you must make `C1` owning the association end to `Implementation`. According to UML specification, this makes the object a property of the other, i.e in most OO langages holding a reference. Graphically this may be expressed with the "**[dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf)**": a tiny dot on the end of the association on `Implementation` side. Unfortunately, many low-cost tools don't support it.
- Another alternative is to name the [association end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648635/what-is-an-association-end-in-uml) in the diagram, with the name of the reference stored in C1 (this is called the "role" in UML).  You an easily do this [in plantuml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60226784/3723423).
- Another way to suggest it, is to use [navigability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/399699/209774); an open arrow on the side of the implementation would mean that You can easily go from `C1` to `Implementation`. It is not as accurate as the dot notation, but readers will understand what you intend to do.

You can have double dot, name both ends, and double navigation to show that each object knows the other.

Adding an artificial second association, as in you second diagram, is not to be recommended, because according to your narrative, the references in your code only implement one and the same association. Two associations should be used only if there are two different relations (e.g. for a car, having a driver and a passenger)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you changed the names it might look like this:

[image]

That's from the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Notice that `Subject` (your `Implementation`) receives an `Observer` (your `C1`) through `attach()`. So long as that `Observer` has access to `Subject`, so it can call that method, it can "set it self as a member". Well, get itself added to a member collection at least.

You can see an example of code doing this on that same Wikipedia page. The [C++ example listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#C++) shows `ConcreteObserver` adding and removing itself in it's constructor and destructors using `concreteSubject->attach(this);` and `concreteSubject->detach(this);` respectively.

If you're looking at that diagram and thinking you can't really see an object attaching itself that's because a UML class diagram is the wrong kind of diagram to show this. To see this properly you should be looking at a UML sequence diagram:

[image]

You can see the pass on the first line here. Yes it used `o1` rather than `this` but that's just a context thing. You're looking at `o1` passing itself.

Comment: Subject would be my C1.. @candied_orange

Comment: C1 has child implementations of a type Contact. Types of Contact hold a reference to C1

Comment: This example also uses associations, instead of aggregation ???

Comment: Should Subject not aggregate Observers

Comment: Re: "Subject would be my C1" Honestly since you were asking what the pictures should look like I ignored them and took "implementation will at some point receive a class of type C1" to be your requirement. In my answer Subject will at some point receive a class of type Observer.

Comment: If that was a simple mistake feel free to edit to correct it. I don't mind updating my answer.

Comment: @TenJones "associations, instead of aggregation ?" - in this example both the observer and the subject can exist and function without referencing the other object (that is, they can be otherwise useful on their own, there just wouldn't be notifications going back and forth). Think of association being a kind of "default" relationship - it just means that one object is referencing another. An aggregation *is also* an association, it's just a more specialized version of it - so it's not a mistake to use the more general relationship, especially in the initial phase of modeling, ... 1/2

Comment: ... when you're not sure what it should be. Aggregation means the same thing, but in addition, you're specifying that the thing at the other end is somehow a part of the referencing (owning) class (the owner is not conceptually "whole" without it, but doesn't necessarily control the part's lifecycle). You shouldn't have a circular dependency with aggregations (it shouldn't be "contract has a C1, and C1 has a contract", similar to how you wouldn't have "car has a tire, a tire has a car", where "has a" is something like "contains as a part" or "is, in part, made out of"). 2/2